# Running jUnit 3 Testsuite with custom Testrunner

Tags: java, junit

I'm running a jUnit 3 Testcase via jUnit4/Eclipse.

Here is my custom JUnit38ClassRunner:

```
public class CR extends JUnit38ClassRunner{...}
```

So I run my Testcase:

```
@RunWith(CR.class)
public class TC extends TestCase
{...}
```

Everything works fine...

Here is my Testsuite:

```
public class TS {
public static Test suite() {
    TestSuite result = new TestSuite();
    result.addTest(new TestSuite(TC.class));
    return result; 
} }
```

How can i achieve, that TC is running through my custom runner CR in this Testsuite?

Thanks